# Rails - Scaffold - controller setup - unknownFormat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have been using Rails scaffolds to build a Rails 4 app.

My current problem is set out below - which arrives when I try and render the articles new page in my app:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

It's referring to the create action in the articles controller (it extracts this error location):

```
@article = Article.new(article_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @article.save
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
  else
```

I have an articles controller with:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # respond_to :html
# GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  # GET /articles/1
  # GET /articles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /articles/new
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /articles
  # POST /articles.json
  def create
    # before_action :authenticate_user!
    # authorize @article
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1.json
  def update
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    authorize @article
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update(article_params)
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /articles/1
  # DELETE /articles/1.json
  def destroy
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    authorize @article
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def article_params
      params[:article].permit(:body, :title, :image,
        comment_attributes: [:opinion])
    end
end
```

I have respond with html in the top line of the controller. I don't know why or what this does. I have read others problems which say you need to give it something to respond to, or use the responder gem. I don't want anything extraordinary - I just want the page to render.

Can anyone see what's wrong here?

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying to do. This looks like an create and show action mashed together. Can you provide more details? Are you using JSON intentionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need a `format.html` so you can add this:

```
@article = Article.new(article_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @article.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@article,
                    :notice => 'Article was successfully created.') }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
  else
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
  end
end
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Why does the scaffold generate something that doesnt work?

Comment: I have done to try scaffold a couple weeks ago in my project to use rails 4. It generates and works properly. Perhaps, it something happens in rails gem. What version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't trying to do anything extraordinary, here's how I would clean up this controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, except: [:new, :create, :index]

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @article.update_attributes(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy 
    if @article.destroy
      redirect_to articles_path
    else
      redirect_to @article
    end
  end

  private

  def set_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def article_params
    params[:article].permit(:body, :title, :image,
      comment_attributes: [:opinion])
  end
end
```

Note that I stripped out your authorization, so add it back in when everything is working.